# VS Code not recognizing transition property

Tags: visual-studio-code

here's my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">



<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>


<body>
    
<header>

            <img src="neo-cryptocurrency-logo.svg" alt="">
            

           
            
            <ul>

                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Faq</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" style="color: white;">Sign Up</a></li>

            </ul>

</header>


<input type="checkbox" id="menu" class="menu">
           <label for="menu">       <svg class="menu-bar" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);transform: msFilter;"><path d="M4 6h16v2H4zm4 5h12v2H8zm5 5h7v2h-7z"></path></svg>
           </label>
    <div class="vertical-menu">
            
        <ul>

            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Faq</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" style="color: white;">Sign Up</a></li>

        </ul>

           </div>

<main>

            <div class="content">
                    
                <h1>DIGITAL</h1>
                <h4>MARKETING</h4>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi qui quod, praesentium impedit sapiente officiis explicabo eius similique doloremque nam facilis consectetur laboriosam repellendus assumenda rem. Harum iure temporibus assumenda.
                Itaque a distinctio nisi libero, illum sint corrupti harum eaque nulla praesentium, veniam ullam labore vero rerum quibusdam doloremque culpa dolore dignissimos et veritatis dolor officia nesciunt! A, aut cum.</p>
                <button>Learn More</button>


            </div>

            <img src="webdev.svg" alt="">


</main>





</body>
</html>
```

and here's my css code:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* border: 1px solid black; */
}

img {
    display: block;
}

/* HEADER */

body {
 font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif ;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 10px 10px 12px 12px;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    
}

header img {
    max-width: 6%;
    min-width: 70px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.menu-bar {
    display: none;
}

.vertical-menu {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(122, 194, 122);
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: start;
    display: none;
    

}

.vertical-menu li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 30px;
    
}

.vertical-menu a {
    
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    
}

.menu {
    display: none;
}

.vertical-menu li:last-child {
    
    background-color: darkcyan;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
    
}

header ul {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 80px;
    align-items: center;
    
}

header li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-inline: 12px;
    
}


header a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}
header a:any-link {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

header a:hover {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

header li:last-child {
    
    
    padding: 12px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.623);

}

header li:last-child:hover {
    
    background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.9);

}


header li a::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: darkcyan;
    transition: .5s;
}

header li a:hover::after {
    
    width: 100%;
    
}


/* MAIN */

main {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    
    margin-top: 50px;
}

main img {
    max-width: 50%;
    min-width: 750px;
}
.content {
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 30px;
    
}

.content h1,h4 {
    line-height: 50px;
}

.content h1 {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 45px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.content h4 {
    font-weight: 450;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    color:  rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.8);
    
    
}

.content p {
    line-height: 24px;
}
.content button {
    border: none;
    background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.7);
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 12px;
    padding-right: 23px;
    padding-left: 23px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 13px;
}

.content button:hover {

    background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.9);
}


/* MEDIA QUERIES */



@media screen and (max-width: 1250px) {
        
   main {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    

    header ul {
        justify-content: end;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    

}

@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
        
   

    main img {
        min-width: 600px;
    }
    

}

@media screen and (max-width: 706px) {
        
   

    header ul {
        display: none;
    }

    

    .menu-bar {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-right: 25px;
        
    }

    .menu {
        display: none;
    }

    .vertical-menu {
        transform: scale(1,0);
        
        transition: transform 2s ease-in-out;
       
        }

    .menu:checked ~ .vertical-menu {
        display: block;
        justify-content: center;
        
        transform: scale(1,1);
    }
    
    
    
    .vertical-menu li {
        text-align: center;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 567px) {
        
   

    main img {
        min-width: 450px;
    }
    
    

}

@media screen and (max-width: 467px) {
        
   

    main img {
        min-width: 350px;
    }
    
    

}

@media screen and (max-width: 363px) {
        
   

    main img {
        min-width: 280px;
    }
    
    

}
```

my problem is no matter what property i use in transition property, vs code does not recognize it. i would appreciate anyone that helps me.

here's the screenshot of it, basically whatever property i use in transition. it's written in white color:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWN3L.png)

Comment: so? what's wrong with it being coloured white? is that the only "problem"?

Comment: When it's white, it means it does not recognize it. So the code it doesn't work.

Comment: syntax highlighting is orthogonal to whether code works or not. show the error message you get at runtime and the observed behaviour and how it differs from the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install any package for them ?

You can try install package in `Extension: Marketplace` Page in Vscode.

Open Extension page on navigation bar or with `Ctrl + Shift + X` combination.

Type Html or Css or whatever package do you want to use and install it.

Comment: What package do i need to install to fix this issue?

Comment: try this https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ecmel.vscode-html-css . 
type html in marketplace, install HTML CSS Support .